# How do i fix a div vertically but not horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my setup:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header">
        this is the header part. i want to be able to scroll this one horizontally but not vertically
    </div>    
</div>

<div id="maincontent">
    here some text just to show that the div is scrolling vertically.
</div>
```

In CSS I have set the `#header-container` position to `fixed` so it works well and does not scroll vertically and horizontally

But what I want to happen is to fix the `#header-container` div vertically and be able to scroll it horizontally so that when I resize the window screen I can still read the whole content of the `#header` div by scrolling

Thanks in advance! Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twish/f548x/)

Comment: A smarter idea would be to make the header a dynamic width so that there is no need to scroll horizontally. However if you're *determined* to use javascript to fix it, you'll have to use `absolute` positioning, change the `top` position on `window.onscroll`, and then make the width of the page as wide as the header (since it's positioned absolutely it isn't automatically detected)

Comment: @Twish Not sure what do you want.. Please explain it better

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any aesthetic or design value in making the header scrollable.  A better approach is to resize the content of the header or to remove portions of it whenever the browser space is at a premium.  Media queries could be quite useful for that.

If you still want to make the header content scrollable, then you can add the overflow-x: auto declaration to the header-container.  Whenever there is not enough horizontal space, the scroll bar will pop and a user will be able to scroll horizontally.  But, like I said, that's not the best design.

A couple of comments about your code.  First, the header's height could be a 100%.  That way you need to only resize the header-container and its header child will scale accordingly.  Second, absolute positioning should be used for precise placement of elements.  In your case, the position: absolute and left: 40px declarations can be replaced with just one margin-left: 40px, which is a lot more economical.